# django db migration concurrently

Tags: django, concurrency, migration

I have multiple django apps connect to the same mysql db backend for high availability purpose. My question is, is it a problem if app instances try to migrate db concurrently? If so, what's the best way to prevent it?

Comment: Concurrently? Yes, that's a problem. I don't believe there's a standard way to avoid it.

Comment: I'm facing same problem, maybe a distributed lock will resolve it.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it concurrently, you'll end up messing up the entire schema, to a point where you'll have to drop your DB and create a new one. Sequentially is the way to go about it. As every instance of the app will require the latest copy of the ****_migrations.py.

Comment: using the default migrate django method works well, just use that it will migrate each app after the other